# How do I include a screenshot to illustrate a question in AskUbuntu?

Tags: support, image

The title is the question.  I have screenshots that make a question easier to understand than anything I can write.

Answer (score 7):

You need [10 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user) to be able to post images. Until then we will be happy to edit your post to include your screenshot once you provided the link to it.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, in your case the problem is your reputation. As a [new user](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user), you cannot post pictures. We will update the posts for you, until you gain the privilege to do so.

The simplest solution, once you can, would be clicking the `img` button on the editing form, or using the shortcut it shows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>):

[image: Screenshot 1]

This then prompts you with another mask which allow direct upload and linking and thus automatically inserts the necessary code:

[image: Screenshot 2]

If you do not want to use this mask, however, you can click the `Images` button on the help bar, which shows the markup:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: You forgot to include that it requires 10 rep.  See Takkat's answer here.

Comment: @LordofTime Which is why I upvoted Takkat's answer myself. ;) But I guess I'll include it as well.

Comment: INdeed.  I'm just annoyingly evil this way :P