# How do you upload a screenshot?

Tags: support, image

I just installed Kazam, and it looks very simple to use. I want to use it here on askubuntu. I figured out how to take a screenshot, I just don't know how to upload it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can add images by following these steps: http://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user

Comment: ok sure, I can do that. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5276/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]
In the editor, there is an image button that will allow you to upload an image into your post.

If you're already hosting your screenshot elsewhere, you can simply link to the image using the standard markup (see 'advanced help' > 'Images'), but the internal hosting method is generally easier and safer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out from now on I will use the 'img' button.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to find a web site to host the image.

I use [imgur](http://imgur.com/) but there are lots of other sites.

Once the image is hosted

**How do I add images to my posts?**:

- HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`
- Markdown `![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`
- the editor toolbar button insert image toolbar button

Taken directly from the [faq](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user)

Comment: Note that using the toolbar button will give you **a place to upload the image automatically!** No searching for image hosts.

Comment: @RobertCartaino If this is the case then shouldn't we be recommending the image button as the preferred method?  There is less risk of images disappearing if another site goes down and the pictures could be automatically removed clearing space when they were not used any more.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why the image button is built into the interface... and why I highlighted it here. The built in image-uploading method safest and best.

Comment: @RobertCartaino In other words, Warren is saying "We should update the FAQ then".

Comment: @Seth Yes, a round of FAQ updates are underway and I pointed the folks heading those efforts to this post.

Comment: I think it is good that the other ways are in the faq, as some content requires linking, and not re-licensed by uploading to imigur.

Comment: Agreed all 3 methods should be given but we could add a note to the faq that using the img button is preferred option so as not to have to rely on external sites unnecessarily and to allow images to be deleted when there are no more questions / answers that link to them.